# Unable to get event listener call back from WebView in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, web, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I have my mobile application build using Xamarin forms, which consist of a webView loaded into my application. The WebView Consist of buttons and icons being loaded. I have a requirement to make the button event Listener  being called , so that I can do the corresponding functionality. Can anyone help me in how to get the button events being called in Xamarin forms.

source code:

```
Control.SetWebViewClient(new HybridWebViewClient());
            Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebClient(mContext));

            Control.LoadUrl(Control.Url);

 internal class HybridWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {


            public override async void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)


            {
                base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

                int i = 10;
                while (view.ContentHeight == 0 && i-- > 0)
                
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    // find the particular button
                    
                    string funcurl = " var btn1 =document.getElementsByClassName('inspectionStartingBtnClose')[0]; if(btn1 != null){btn1.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('dosomething'); })";
                    view.LoadUrl("javascript: r(function(){" + funcurl + "");
                

            }

        }
```

Comment: You can check the [this case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d3ae4e9-e77c-4445-8fcb-ff1a470463ee/get-webview-button-click-event?forum=xamarinforms) and do that according to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#invoke-c-from-javascript).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - can you confirm If the above code is working one?

Comment: This is the code in the official document which show how to call the C# method in the JavaScript.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - Currently I'm not able to get the button event using the above code? could you please provide a working sample for the same?

Comment: There is already a sample in the official document, did you try to clone it to your visual studio?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - yes. I have tried with the same sample. but I'm getting an error message "data is undefined ".

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I have posted another question with the sample code . can you guide me on that?

Comment: Did you try to find which line caused this error?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - you can find the code in the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629404/unable-to-get-the-trigger-button-event-call-back-from-web-view-for-xamarin-using

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - `
            hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => Console.WriteLine("value of data is" + data));` I'm getting the log printed as "data is undefined "

Comment: You can try to add the `webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;` and the `webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;` into the `OnElementChanged` method in the HybridWebViewRenderer.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - still I'm getting the same error. 'value of data is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247913/discussion-between-im-coder-and-liyun-zhang-msft).

Comment: you can find the solution for in the below mentioned link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629404/unable-to-get-the-trigger-button-event-call-back-from-web-view-for-xamarin-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using TestProject.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Vinspector.HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]

namespace TestProject.Droid
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
       
    const string JavascriptFunction= "document.getElementById('btnId').onclick= function(data){jsBridge.submissionAction(data);}";`

        Context _context;

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("print inside  control is null!!!");
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
                webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                SetNativeControl(webView);


            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
                Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
               webView.SetWebViewClient(new `JavascriptWebViewClient(this,string.Format("javascript: {0}", JavascriptFunction)));`
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
                Control.LoadUrl(“www.google.com”);


            }
        }
   

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```